# Exporting atlas using "filter by" fields

Tags: qgis, filter, atlas

The "filter by" option in the Atlas dialogue doesn't seem to work for me. When I create a filter using an expression consisting of several fields, the atlas export includes pages which *should* be excluded from the export.
For example, this filter expression:

```
"siteType" = 'site-type-1'
AND
"siteCity" = 'London'
AND
$area > 250
```

...returns a whole load of sites which have an area of below 250sqm and are in cities other than London, rather than strictly adhering to the filters I've set.

I can't figure out why this is happening. I'm sure that I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know what. I can't find any guidance on how to create atlas filters which filter by several different variables.

Comment: Difficult to say, you should add more information. Where do you set the filter? How is your project structured? You filter the coverage layer? Can you share a dummy project with sample data to reproduce the behaviour?

Comment: I tried creating a dummy project with 22 polygons and the fields you  have, with differnt values. Only features 2 fulfill all three conditions and the atlas is created just for these two features of the coverage layer, using your filter. So not sure what settings you have. Try 1) creating a new boolean field in your attribute table with your expression to create true/false values, then 2) filter by this attribute. Like this you see if the wrong features are selected (step  1) or the filter (step 2) doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't use `$area`**

The value of `$area` is based on an ellipsoidal calculation that uses the
ellipsoid as set in the project settings. The units it reports are the ones set in the project settings. This may not be what you want.

You might want to try `area($geometry)`. I believe that works more intuitively
because it calculates planimetrically, based on the layer's CRS, and reports in
the CRS' units.

Comment: Not sure if that is the OP's (main) problem - they mention that also features are created "in cities other than London", so the problem seems to be the filter as such and not so much the kind of area calculations. But as long as we have no further information, we can only speculate.